# C/C++ Debugging in Emacs 23.1

Tags: debugging, emacs

I use gdb version 7.0 for debugging from emacs. The gdb when launched from emacs behaves slighlty differently compared with one launched from the shell. The points of differences are :-

1. gdb prompt, when launched from emacs doesn't recogonize the files in the current directory (from which the gdb session is launched.) This very cumbersome as when you run the application through gdb (using run), you have to give the full absolute path of the file. This is not the case when you launch the application through gdb from shell.
2. The arrow keys (that give the most recent commands typed on the gdb prompt), doesn't work for gdb launched from emacs. Instead, it moves the scroll up and down in the emacs gdb command prompt. Am I doing anything wrong here.. ?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

1. since you are in a buffer, up and down move up and down in the buffer.  most of the emacs shell-like buffers access the command history using "C-up" and "C-down".

Comment: Hi,      Thanks for the command. It seems to access the history. Is there any thing required to be done to increase the length of the history that is stored. It just shows History length : 1 and run as the command. I have used 'n' and 's' in gdb , which are not shown.

Comment: For the (1.) part of the question, I figured out that we need to 'cd' to the desired path once from the gdb prompt, as emacs moves itself to the location of the binary launched in gdb.

Comment: @rob - i would assume the history is a decent length, i don't know how to change the setting though.  i don't quite understand what you mean, though, when you say "It just shows History length : 1 and run as the command."

Comment: yes. you are right. The history has a decent enough length. What I meant was the history shows only 'run' (command of gdb) as present and nothing else.